# N-ary Tree Postorder Traversal using recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree, traversal

Working on a problem of the n-ary tree traversal using recursion I came up with some difficulty understanding part of someones else's solution.

Basically this is my question.

```
if(root === null){
    return [];
}

let arr = [];
traverse(root);

function traverse(root){
    if(root.children === null){
        arr.push(root.val);
        return;
    }
    for(let i = 0; i < root.children.length; i++){
        traverse(root.children[i]);    
        console.log(arr);
    }
    
    arr.push(root.val);
}
return arr;
```

For the base case I am checking if the children of the given node are to be found and if not I add them to the array. What I don't understand is the some solutions don't use push() but just return arr?
This looks strange to me but that way solution works as well.

Can someone explain how is it possible that alto we just return the array(arr) and don't explicitly add the node value to it this solution still works?

## Update

This is what confuses me.

```
if(root.children === null){
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: `return (function traverse(acc, node){ if(node) { if(node.children) acc = node.children.reduce(traverse, acc); acc.push(node.val); } return acc; })([], root);`

Comment: *"What I don't understand is the some solutions don't use push() but just return arr? ... Can someone explain how is it possible"*  simple, you just have to ... seriously, how should we explain to you how a code works that you do not show? *"this is what I did, others did something different, why is theirs working if it is not like mine?"*

Comment: `root.children === null` will be reached when there are no more child elements to traverse - in other words, this is the check that ends the recursive call to `traverse`  and passes the result back up the call stack.  -  What's weird in this algorithm is that, it doesn't use tail call recursion, you could as well return the current value concated with the recursive result.